# BarButtonItem not appearing

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have  a simple + button on the right side to add rows to my tableView, however the button is not appearing. This is how i implement it

```
    let AddButton = UIButton()
    AddButton.setTitle("+", forState: .Normal)
    let AddView = UIBarButtonItem(customView: AddButton)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = AddView
            AddButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.addRow), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Note, I use the same exact implementation for my hamburger button which does appear. This is the working hamburger button implementation

```
    let navicon = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    navicon.setImage(defaultMenuImage(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    navicon.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    let menu = UIBarButtonItem(customView: navicon)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menu
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    navicon.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
let AddButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
AddButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)
```